# What is the word for over reading something positively?

Tags: single-word-requests

So there's usually that scenario where you misinterpret what someone is saying too positively, for example a girl says yes to a statement, and you think it means she accepted the intent behind the statement, et cetera. I found overread but there doesn't seem to be a generally accepted definition of the word in this regard.

Comment: Sounds like wishful thinking: I believe something is true because that's what I am wishing.

Comment: _Wishful thinking_ is indeed the idiom you're looking for.

Comment: For "overreading", the usual idiom is "reading too much into something" but it's not necessarily positive - [see this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79557/what-is-the-meaning-of-dont-read-too-much-here).

Comment: Wishful thinking is more of thinking than overreading positively into something.

Comment: That's what you think. But you asked, remember? And _overreading_ is not idiomatic English, unless it means actually reading too much (_He has overread Shakespeare and now he plans to start on Dickens_).

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wishful-thinking

Comment: I find it nearly offensive to say I was wishfully thinking because I was not. There are times when a partial yes implies a full yes or it's not absolutely clear depending on the context, assuming it means a full yes is more of *positive thinking* than *wishful thinking*

Comment: This is clearly about sex. And it is just hearing yes or no. There is no "overhearing". And this is not at all clever.

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed English StackExchange was so judgmental. Unbelievable! Maybe the exemplary context was wrong and sensitive but gosh the replies! Unbelievable!

Answer (score 2):

[**Wishful thinking**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishful_thinking) is making real life conform to your wishes. It's trusting that what you want is what you actually get, and giving no weight to the heavy fantasy element.

Wikipedia entry:

> Wishful thinking is the formation of beliefs based on what might be pleasing to imagine, rather than on evidence, rationality, or reality. It is a product of resolving conflicts between belief and desire.
>
> ... Various disciplines and schools of thought examine related mechanisms such as:
>
> - neural circuitry
> - human cognition and emotion
> - types of bias
> - procrastination
> - motivation
> - optimism
> - attention
> - environment
>
> This concept has been examined as a fallacy.

> Some psychologists believe that positive thinking is able to positively influence behavior and so bring about better results ... called the *Pygmalion effect*.

In addition, similar assumptions are built into the expressions "I must have been **reading too much** into it" and "Sorry for **putting words in your mouth**."

Comment: I was actually hoping this was a thing, most people respond to these kind of situations with 'can I take that as a yes'.. When you take it as a yes without permission and the other takes offence, and you're appealing, how do you say what your offence is in an easy way.